# Creating an automatic closing time for registrations with a discord bot

Tags: discord.py

I've been learning how to make a discord bot for a while and for the most part I've grasped the fundamentals already and I'm working my way through the more advanced concepts.

At the moment, I'm stuck on formulating the logic on making a time out with registrations.

So for example, I set up a tournament with a set deadline for registrations, what would be a good approach to close the registrations?

At the moment I already have the deadline saved in the database and whenever users register via a command, it checks if the current date is > the deadline date. But this I want the bot to be able to send a message by itself and prompt in the channel that "Registrations are closed".

I realized wait_for only waits for a single command. If I put that in a loop, I have to set how many registrations I should wait for (but with this I can use reacts).

A scheduler would have to loop every few minutes/hours and check if current datetime is > deadline which isn't very accurate.

The good thing is, there can only be one tournament at a time running.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch current event from your database in `on_ready`, wait for that event and then send a message to channel (You also can store channel_id in your database).
Check the example below.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    event_data = something  # fetch current event data from your database
    if event_data[‘end_time’] > datetime.utcnow().tinestamp():
        await asyncio.sleep(event_data[‘end_time'] - datetime.utcnow().timestamp())  # wait for event
        channel = bot.get_channel(event_data[‘channel_id’])
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.send(“Event has been finished!”)
    # you can delete this event from your database here
```

You also can use scheduler to schedule a task instead of `asyncio.wait()`. For example **[APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/)**.